# Logitech M185 Wireless Mouse works fine on one PC but not another?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, logitech-mouse

I'm having an issue with a Logitech M185 mouse - a user is unable to use the device.

The device works perfectly fine on my PC (It appears as HID-compliant mouse), but not on her laptop.  It does not appear in her device manager on the 'Mice and other pointing devices' section.

I did notice an unknown device in the Universal Serial Bus Controllers section, but when I try to update the driver, it says it has the most up to date driver.

We've tried plugging in the dongle in multiple USB slots but no luck.

Any advice?

It's a HP 620 Laptop on Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After uninstalling the Universal Serial Bus Controllers and restarting, installing the Logitech drivers, changing the USB socket I plugged the mouse in to, it turns out that none of these were the answer.

The issue was with the USB ports not working, they would not accept ANY device.

The way to resolve this on the HP 620 Notebook was by installing the latest BIOS software.  This provided a fix straight away as the BIOS on this notebook was 2 months out of date.

Comment: well there you go

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the Logitech SetPoint software?  If not, download it from [here](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/wireless-mouse-m185?osid=14&bit=32).  The SetPoint software will pair the receiver and mouse allowing you to use it on your computer.

Comment: I've installed the Logitech Software, no luck.  I'm starting to think this is more an issue with the Laptop's usb ports rather than the mouse itself.

Answer (score 1):

Some months Back i was having similar problem for using [Logitech M185 Wireless Mouse](https://www.vplak.com/logitech-m185-wireless-mouse-p13) with My Lenovo Laptop. I updates the BIOS Software and it works fine then.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Could you [edit] your post and add the BIOS version? It may help other users.